# JAX-RS Application in JBoss EAP 6.4 - JBWEB000260

Tags: java, rest, jboss, jax-rs, jboss-eap-6

I'm converting an older web application from Tomcat to JBoss EAP 6.4. Its REST-services had been using Jersey which I'm removing because JBoss EAP 6.4 includes RESTeasy and the resources are using jax-rs annotations only.

For each service I've added an application extends `java.ws.rs.core.Application`, e.g.:

```
package x.rest.external;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

public class ExternalApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<>();
        classes.add(ResourceY.class);
        classes.add(ResourceZ.class);
        return classes;
    }
}
```

I want to use no RESTeasy or JBoss specific method to declare this service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    [...]

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>x.rest.external.ExternalApplication</servlet-name>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>x.rest.external.ExternalApplication</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/external/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    [...]

>
```

As far as I can tell from the specification and various web sources, this should suffice to get the service up and running. But if I'm calling the service all I get is:

```
10:54:51,630 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/x]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) JBWEB000289: Servlet x.rest.external.ExternalApplication threw load() exception: javax.servlet.ServletException: JBWEB000260: No servlet class has been specified for servlet x.rest.external.ExternalApplication
```

I know there are ways to use some RESTeasy servlet or use annotation only configurations. I want the application to stay as container independent as possible and think base paths should all be declared in the `web.xml` descriptor.

**EDIT**: seems to boil down to [RESTEASY-650](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RESTEASY-650) and [RESTEASY-738](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RESTEASY-738) which are fixed in RESTeasy 3.x but JBoss EAP 6.4 ships with 2.3.x.

To avoid the `org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011232: Only one JAX-RS Application Class allowed` exception I've to disable all resteasy scan in web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan.providers</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan.resources</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

which in turn let JBoss choking on unspecified servlets: `javax.servlet.ServletException: JBWEB000260: No servlet class has been specified`.

If I disable all but one JAX-RS applications both using `@ApplicationPath` and `web.xml` declarations work.

**EDIT 2:** runs fine in JBoss EAP 7.0 beta.

Comment: According to the spec it _should_ work. Try annotating the application class with `@ApplicationPath("/rest/external")` instead.

Comment: Doesn't seem to get picked up. No exceptions, log messages and constructor isn't called at all.

Comment: Even if you comment out the whole web.xml?

Comment: Don't think this would change anything. But I've had accidentally removed the single line  `<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jaxrs:1.0"/>` element together with the default infinispan configuration. Now I get `org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011232: Only one JAX-RS Application Class allowed.` if I don't disable resteasy scanning. Which is unfortunate because the services are configured differently. So back to declaring those application in `web.xml`.

Comment: If JBoss is running with it's default configurations, JAX-RS (RESTeasy) should be loaded by default, and either of the discussed ways _should_ just work; either your web.xml (which adheres the spec) or the annotation I mentioned, which also adheres to the spec. So I'm not sure what you've change that would cause it not to work. You can install a fresh new JBoss, and I'm pretty sure it should work, as long as you don't disable anything in the jboss-deployment-structure

Comment: I think because you have both the web.xml and the @ApplicationPath. These are two different ways to configure, and it may be that both ways are working and it's trying to load the application class twice

Comment: No, I've tested both ways separatly. Annotations don't work because of [RESTEASY-738](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RESTEASY-738).